# Importing my module makes the program run on its own

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a python program that is used as a calculator. I decided to learn how to import it into other programs so I added:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ive tried importing my module a lot of times and all it does is run the main function with just the import statement on the editor. All i do is type import calculator and it just runs it. I'm not very sure what the if **name** statement does so if someone would also elaborate on how it helps importing my program, that would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you still have something outside of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` that runs the code anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: @toonarmycaptain I don't think that's a dupe of this. This question asks that question off-hand, but this question is really asking "How come my code runs on import when I have its execution inside an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block", rather than "What does `if __name__ == "__main__"` do"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` condition checks if you are running the script via python interpreter and calls the `main()` function. For more detailed explanation refer to this question [What does if **name** == “**main**”: do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

If you have a program like this

```
# script.py
def hello_world():
    print "Hello World!"

hello_world()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`Hello World!` would be printed whether you import `script.py` or run it from command line like `python script.py`, because the function `hello_world()` is executed in both instances.

**Case 1: Running from command line**

```
$ python script.py
Hello World!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/tests/script.py", line 8, in <module>
    main()
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

**Case 2: Importing as module**

```
>>> import script
Hello World!
```

If you want to stop it from being printed, then wrap the executing part of the code in the main function like this:

```
def hello_world():
        print "Hello World!"

def main():
    hello_world()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now, `hello_world()` gets called (or `Hello World!` gets printed) only when you run it as a script and not when you import it as a module.

Answer (score 0):

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more information on `if __name__ == "__main__"`, but the quick excerpt is

> Before executing the code, it will define a few special variables. For example, if the python interpreter is running that module (the source file) as the main program, it sets the special `__name__` variable to have a value `"__main__"`. If this file is being imported from another module, `__name__` will be set to the module's name.

So any code included in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block will only be run if you call `python mymodule.py`. It will NOT run if you call `python importsmymodule.py`.

As for your specific issue, without seeing the code for the calculator module it's impossible to tell, but it seems self-evident that *something* in your script is calling the calculator to start.